# Azure SQL Database connection with my MSSQL server on my pc

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection

I cannot connect to the database in the sql server in Azure. I cannot connect in any way, regardless of mssql server or visual studio on my own computer. I get my connection information from azure and try to login as below but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any information about the solution?

[image]

I have tried almost all entities related to my username. Other than that, access-related settings cannot be changed, I was not very successful.[mssql login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubRsW.png) [my azure server proporties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1uyj.png) [my azure server proporties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NpjJ.png)

Comment: Why are you using SSMS 2012? I don't even recall if that *does* that even support Azure SQL Database? Why are you not using the latest release?

Comment: To authenticate using "Azure Active Directory with MFA" you need SSMS 18.6 at a bare minimum, so you could save yourself a lot of trouble if you just upgrade to the latest available version of SSMS.

Comment: Always use the latest version of SSMS with Azure. Older versions are unaware of newer features, including security improvements. Add the error message to your question rather than only say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you add Server admin name in SSMS Login and Password which was given while creation of the SQL Server in Azure.

Share error details which you get in Azure Portal Query Editor or SSMS to investigate further.

Comment: I have attached images of the errors. it seems i am using the correct username but i keep getting login error.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL username contain **@** in it then use the username followed by **`@servername`**.

**Example:**  `bob@consto.com@<servername>`

**My SQL Server admin:**

[image]

**Details for connection:**

[image]

**If you are using Active directory authentication you need to add AD user as Azure AD admin in SQL server**

[image]

**Successful connection:**

[image]